# ASP.NET session timeout: What is the order of precedence?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

There appears to be many places to change the session timeout for an ASP.NET application. For example,

1. At the Application Pool level containing the application,
2. At the Application Pool node level containing all appPools,
3. In the web site properties dialog, ASP.NET tab, Edit Configuration,
4. In the web site properties dialog, ASP.NET tab, Edit Global Configuration,
5. In the application's web.config,
6. In the machine's config files.

I may have missed some, who knows. This is what I've found so far. So the question, what is the order of precedence for the session timeout? Which setting overrides the others?

Thanks!

Comment: And of course directly in code using the HttpContext.Session.Timeout property ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the other answers:

ASP.NET configuration works by inheriting values, starting with the most general, and working down to the most specific:

Starting in the Microsoft.Net\Framework\vX.Y.ZZZ\Config folder

a. machine.config - Point 6
b. web.config - Possibly point 4, I've not played around with this one too much
c. web_[Level]trust.config - If you've declared a trust level for your site

I believe the Application Pool settings would then kick in here:

d. App Pool Node - Point 2
e. Application Pool for the application - Point 1

Then moving on to the website:

f. web.config - Point 3 and 5 
g. Application code (setting `HttpContext.Session.Timeout` directly in code) - I believe this only sets the current request's timeout, rather than affecting the application timeout.

Answer (score 1):

3 and 5 are points to the same setting and they override all others.

Answer (score 1):

i think 3==5 and 4==6

local web.config overrides global machine.config

i am not sure about application pools, there are no session timeouts in 1 and 2, not in IIS 7.5 anyways.

Answer (score 1):

3==5 and 4==6 just like Artemiy said.  As for 1 and 2 I think he's referring to setting the timeout on the application pools, which will also reset the session.

It's been my experience that the local application configurations will override the global settings, but for the app pool settings and the local web.config settings I don't think there is an order of precedence.  It's a matter of whichever one has the shortest timeout will be triggered first.  This is my experience with iis6, 7 may handle it differently.

Also keep in mind if there are any changes in the directory of the application, like changing the web.config, it will reset the application and reset the sessions.  Virus scanners are notorious for doing this.