# Why does the timeout setting in IIS web.config seem to have no effect.

Tags: iis, timeout

I have the following settings in web.config (IIS v6):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".xyzauth" protection="All" timeout="360" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

I understand this to mean that the session will timeout after 6 hours (360 minutes). However, I get prompted for a new login somewhere between 5 and 15 minutes. **What might be causing this?** I have searched the whole project for other timeout of sessionState references but have found nothing. The project is from an external company who claim to be 'innocent'. The project uses the Infragistics framework.

Any ideas?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580274/how-to-stop-session-timeout-after-20minutes-in-asp-net/10580322#10580322

Comment: @Romil - that looks very promising. Testing the timeout now.... :-)