# Reset Session timeout if the user is active in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to reset the session timeout if the user is active with in the session timeout.

means:

Let an user is logged in to a system whose session time out is 10 min. if the user do some operation with that timeout then the session time out will start when the user is inactive.

if the user is again do so operation then the session time out will be rest.

how to do this one.

please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put follow configuration in your web.config

```
<sessionState timeout="10" />
```

**MSDN says:**

Optional TimeSpan attribute.

Specifies the number of minutes a session can be idle before it is abandoned. The timeout attribute cannot be set to a value that is greater than 525,600 minutes (1 year) for the in-process and state-server modes.

The session timeout configuration setting applies only to ASP.NET pages. Changing the session timeout value does not affect the session time-out for ASP pages. Similarly, changing the session time-out for ASP pages does not affect the session time-out for ASP.NET pages.

The default is 20 minutes.

reference:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Server will `Automatically` reset the Session Time Out , once the user becomes active.

There is not explicit code required to accomplish this..just setting the Session time out would be good enough..

**Updated:**

Then you should be worth looking at this:

[How to stop session timeout after 20minutes in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580274/how-to-stop-session-timeout-after-20minutes-in-asp-net)

Hope this helps..

Comment: but in my application session expires after each 20 min :(. how to solve this one.

is there any method to fix the session timeout(means it will not reset the session) i can remove that one

Comment: No its not working for me :(.

i tried all the things written inside that link but my issue is not solved.